# How can I test firebase invite in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, testing, firebase, firebase-invites

I am using firebase invite to invite friends using referral code. And I need to know how can I handle the following scenarios in my iOS application.

I have followed [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/ios) guide for Firebase Invite implementation.

**Case 1:** Application **not installed** on iPhone and user installs the app via invite. I need referral code from the `"deeplink"` parameter set from invitee. or Application installed and **currently not running** user clicks on invite url from email.

**Solution >>** As of my knowledge below code inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method will handle this scenario.

```
if let inviteUrl = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey] as? NSURL {
      //App opened from invite url
      self.handleFirebaseInviteDeeplink(inviteUrl)
}
```

**Case 2:** Application already installed and **currently running** on iPhone and user clicks on invite link inside the email.

**Solution >>** Below methods in AppDelegate will handle the code I assume.

```
@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, options: [String : AnyObject]) -> Bool {
     return self.application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey] as? String, annotation: "")
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
     if let invite = FIRInvites.handleURL(url, sourceApplication:sourceApplication, annotation:annotation) as? FIRReceivedInvite {
        let matchType = (invite.matchType == FIRReceivedInviteMatchType.Weak) ? "Weak" : "Strong"
              print("\n------------------Invite received from: \(sourceApplication) Deeplink: \(invite.deepLink)," + "Id: \(invite.inviteId), Type: \(matchType)")
              if (matchType == "Strong") {
                  print("\n-------------- Invite Deep Link = \(invite.deepLink)")
                  if !invite.deepLink.isEmpty {
                       let url = NSURL(string: invite.deepLink)
                       self.handleFirebaseInviteDeeplink(url!)
                  }
              }
              return true
     }
     return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

The problem is I couldn't find a way to test any of the scenario. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: ...Did you solve an issue?